# How to know for sure this is a low-pass filter

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, z-transform

Given the transfer function

$$H(z) = \frac{1}{4}(1+z^{-1}+z^{-2}+z^{-3})$$

I understand I have to switch $z$ to $e^{j\Omega}$, $0\le\Omega\le\pi$, in order to find out how it interacts with frequencies.

$$H(\Omega)=\frac{1}{4}(1+e^{-j\Omega}-e^{-j2\Omega}-e^{-j3\Omega})$$

And now the amplitude function, $|H(\Omega)|$, would tell us how much of each frequency there would be in our output signal.

However, is it possible to see this is a low-pass filter **without** the help of a computer or tedious calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z=1$ (the zero frequency) we have $|H(1)|=1$ which is clearly the largest possible amplitude since $|H(z)|\le 1$. For other $z$ on the unit circle we can calculate the geometric sum
$$
H(z)=\frac14\cdot\frac{1-z^{-4}}{1-z^{-1}}.
$$
Denoting $z^{-1}=\cos t+i\sin t$ we get
$$
|H(z)|^2=\frac{1}{16}\cdot\frac{1-\cos 4t}{1-\cos t}.
$$
As $t$ grows to $\pi$ the numerator oscillates and stays bounded while the denominator grows, so the latter is damping more and more at higher frequencies.

**Intuition**: in the time domain the filter is acting very simple - it averages the last four input samples. The average of low frequency components remains almost unchanged while the high frequency ones almost cancel each other.

P.S. The filter is called the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) filter. It is one of the simplest low pass filters that can be realized as a [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response#Moving_average_example).